# CSS Ballon google earth

Tags: javascript, google-earth, google-earth-plugin, balloon

How can I change the style of a placemark ballon in google earth? Isn't the kml data, is the ballon itself. For example, I would like to round the border. I do an example but always view a blank border around the style that I put.

Javascript code:

```
var ge=null;
var html="<div class='ews_infobox'> Prueba </div>";
var inicio={"latitud": 43.3667, "longitud": -5.8333,"zoom": 5000.0};


function initCB(pluginInstance) {
ge = pluginInstance;
ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_SHOW);

    //Crea un placemark.
    var placemark = ge.createPlacemark('');

    //Define icono.
    var icon = ge.createIcon('');
    icon.setHref('images/home2.png');

    // Placemark en Oviedo.  
    var point = ge.createPoint('');
    point.setLatitude(43.3667);
    point.setLongitude(-5.8333);
    placemark.setGeometry(point);

    // Add the placemark to Earth.
    ge.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark); 

    //Crea la vista (LookAct).
    ge.getOptions().setFlyToSpeed(.2);
    var lookAt = ge.createLookAt('');

    // Pone las posiciones.
    lookAt.setLatitude(inicio.latitud);
    lookAt.setLongitude(inicio.longitud);
    lookAt.setRange(inicio.zoom);

    // Actualiza vista de google Earth.
    ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);


    eventoMarca(placemark);
}

function eventoMarca(placemark){


google.earth.addEventListener(placemark, 'click', function(event) {


     var balloon = ge.createHtmlDivBalloon('');
      balloon.setFeature(placemark);
      var div = document.createElement('DIV');
      div.innerHTML = html;
      balloon.setContentDiv(div);
      ge.setBalloon(balloon);

    });

}
```

style css:

```
.ews_infobox
{
padding:15px;
color:#000;
background:#f3961c; 
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f9d835), to(#f3961c));
background:-moz-linear-gradient(#f9d835, #f3961c);
background:-o-linear-gradient(#f9d835, #f3961c);
background:linear-gradient(#f9d835, #f3961c);
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
width: 80px;
height: 40px;

}
```

And the ballon is:[ballon](http://es.tinypic.com/r/11c5n2q/5)

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle of what you have so far?

Comment: Yes, [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sandritascs/7mrBU/4/)

Comment: Is it a requirement to use Google Earth? This needs a browser plugin and isn't supported at all on Linux. For most purposes (idk yours), the Google Maps API might be a better choice and is easy to customize.

Comment: I used google maps too, but I need to do it in google earth. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way at all to do this.  You can only change the style of the content, but not the balloon itself.

This is because the 'balloon frame' isn't actually part of the DOM - it is rendered natively by the plugin.